# setDuration for animation works in Genymotion virtual devices, not on actual S4

Tags: android, animation, device, galaxy

I wrote a simple app that uses ObjectAnimator to animate different properties of images and move them across the screen.  It works perfectly in my Genymotion virtual Galaxy S4, but on my real S4 it seems like the images skip the animations and instantly land in their final positions. I tried multiplying the durations by 10000 even, but same result.  Here is some relevant code:

```
ObjectAnimator land1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lander1,"y",lander1.getY(),moon.getY()+80);
land1.setDuration(5000);
ObjectAnimator land1Rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lander1,"rotation",360);
land1Rotate.setRepeatCount(4);
land1Rotate.setDuration(750);

AnimatorSet animSet1 = new AnimatorSet();
animSet1.play(land1).with(land1Rotate);
animSet1.start();
```

Comment: Maybe worth checking if Animation is disabled in developer options?

Comment: That was it!  Actually, I did check that before, but it didn't have any effect, however after your comment I thought maybe I need to restart the phone, and that worked. Thanks Mighter!

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from enabling animations in developer options (see comments above).  As I said, I tried it first off, but I didn't restart, so after trying again plus restarting it worked.